# Cannot convert BLE advertisement data to String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using a standard CentralManager call to get some BLE advertisement data without connecting.
My code snippet is:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
                
        print("The value of ManufacturerData is \(String(describing: advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]))")

        var manufacturerData: String!

        if let mData = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] {
            manufacturerData = String(data: mData as! Data, encoding: UTF8.self)
        }
        else {
            manufacturerData = ""
        }
....
}
```

The print line produces

The value of ManufacturerData is Optional(<3235343a 3834>)

which shows the 2 integer values I want as 254:84 so I know that the values are there.
I can't find a way to get the manufacturerData in a form to start extracting the 2 values.
The error on the 'manufacturerData =' line is

Cannot convert value of type ‘UTF8.Type’ (aka ‘Unicode.UTF8.Type’) to expected argument type ’String.Encoding’

Comment: I tested and `let manufacturerString = String(data: mData as! Data, encoding: .utf8)` works... Then, `let components = manufacturerString.components(separatedBy: ":")` and then `components[0]` & `components[1]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
manufacturerData = String(data: mData as! Data, encoding: UTF8.self)
```

should be

```
manufacturerData = String(data: mData as! Data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Now, to avoid the force unwrap, you could do:

```
if let mData = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey] as? Data {
    manufacturerData = String(data: mData, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

`manufacturerData` then will be `"254:84"`

From that, you can use `components(separatedBy:)`:

```
let components = manufacturerString.components(separatedBy: ":")
let first = components[0] //"254"
let second = components[1] //"84"
```